# What is the best way to find all files on SD card with a certain extension?

Tags: android

What is the best way to find all files with a defined custom extension on the SD card?
Are there any filters or maybe some techniques?

**EDIT:**

What is the best way to find all .txt files on my SD - Card ?

Comment: Usually, you use `MediaStore` to search external storage for file types, though not necessarily by file extension.

Comment: I store on my SD-Card several files with my custom extension(for example file1.abc, file2.abc - it can be like regular .txt file), and these file are stored in different nodes of the file system. How can I find all these files(traverse the whole file system) and store them in a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use standard Java file I/O to traverse the necessary directories and find the files of interest, such as this snippet derived from http://exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/TraverseTree.html

```
public static void visitAllFiles(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            visitAllFiles(new File(dir, children[i]));
        }
    } else {
        // do something with your file
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use MediaStore and FileFilter togther.